# Azure Function AddDeviceAsync

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-iot-hub

I am trying to add a device with "Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Device::AddDeviceAsync(Device)" inside an Azure function with the following code :

```
public static async Task Run(string myQueueItem, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"C# ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message: {myQueueItem}");
    var manager = new Manager();
    RegisterMessage message = manager.ConvertMessage(myQueueItem);
    await manager.AddToHub(log, message.MacAddress);
    log.Info("fin du run");
}

public class Manager {

    string EndpointUrl = "endpoint";
    string PrimaryKey = "key";
    string connectionString = "connectionString";
    RegistryManager registryManager;
    DocumentClient client;

    public Manager() {
        registryManager = RegistryManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);
        client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(EndpointUrl), PrimaryKey);
    }

    public async Task AddToHub(TraceWriter log, string macAddress) {
        string deviceId = this.GenerateUniqueDevice(macAddress);
        var device = new Device(deviceId);
        try {
            await registryManager.AddDeviceAsync(device);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            log.Info($"{e.Message}");
        }
    }

    public RegisterMessage ConvertMessage(string queueItem) {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RegisterMessage>(queueItem);
    }
    private string GenerateUniqueDevice(string macAddress)
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

this code is working perfectly fine on Visual Studio but inside Azure Function portal i got the following error

> 2018-02-28T14:30:28.454 [Info] Function started
>   (Id=3013dd9c-7248-4a01-8a4a-c087595eef97) 2018-02-28T14:30:28.720
>   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.HttpClientHelper.d__36.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>     at >System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotifica>tion(Task task)
>     at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.HttpClientHelper.d__12`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>     at >System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotifica>tion(Task task)
>     at Submission#0.Manager.d__6.MoveNext() in >D:\home\site\wwwroot\PaymentQueueTrigger\run.csx:line 41
>
> ID:041b47841b234f9287236022c701f479-G:7-TimeStamp:02/28/2018
>   14:30:28"} 2018-02-28T14:30:28.798 [Info] Function completed (Success,
>   Id=3013dd9c-7248-4a01-8a4a-c087595eef97, Duration=343ms)

But the device parameter isn't null when I log it.
Any idea ?

Comment: Log the full stack trace not just the error message and update your question.

Comment: done but this is not much more explicit

Comment: How are you picking up connection string/endpoint URL/key when running in Azure? App Settings? Did you try printing them out just to make sure it's what you expect?

Comment: I have hardcoded them at variable initialization by C/C them from the portal, so yes they are the good one :/

Comment: If you're on the v1 function runtime, i guess it's time for some remote debugging - just like a Web App, https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2016/09/22/remote-debug-your-azure-app-service-web-app/

Comment: the problem is it's it works fine on Visual Studio. Also, GetDevicesAsync() works just fine on Azure Function Portal. It is due to GET/POST request ? 
My connectionString allows read/write.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165981/discussion-between-magnas-and-evilsnobu).